# Could not load module 'System.Random'

Tags: haskell

I could not add System.Random module to use it my source haskell file.

```
import System.Random
```

This is the error produced by stack ghc:

```
/Users/admin1/Haskell/PROJECTS/L4/src/Lib4.hs:32:1: error:
Could not load module ‘System.Random’
It is a member of the hidden package ‘random-1.1’.
You can run ‘:set -package random’ to expose it.
(Note: this unloads all the modules in the current scope.)
Use -v (or `:set -v` in ghci) to see a list of the files searched for.
   |
32 | import System.Random
   | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Failed, five modules loaded.
```

Thank you very much in advance.
P.S. I am using Stack and GHC versions: Version 2.3.1, Git revision x86_64 hpack-0.33.0, ghc-8.8.3 on Mac OSX

Comment: Did you add the `random` package to the `build-depends` in the `*.cabal` file?

Comment: OK. It is working now. I did run "stack install random", I also added "- random" to my package.yaml, because I am in stack environment. Now I can "import System.Random" and compile my code. Thank you very much Willem Van Onsem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the error says:

```
It is a member of the hidden package ‘random-1.1’.
```

This likely means that you did not list it in the `build-depends`, and thus it is not exposed to your modules.

You can alter the `.cabal` file, and add it, for example:

```
-- project.cabal file
-- …

executable …
  -- …
  build-depends:
      base >= 4.7 && < 5
    , random >= 1.1
    -- ,  …
```